# protobuf-net: Cannot Serialize using System.Enum property

Tags: c#, enums, protobuf-net

I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do with an example

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(101, typeof(SomeDerived))]
[ProtoInclude(102, typeof(AnotherDerived))]
public abstract class Base
{
    protected Base() {}
    public Base(double doubleProp, Enum enumProp)
    {
        DoubleProp = doubleProp;
        EnumProp = enumProp;
    }
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public double DoubleProp { get; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Enum EnumProp { get; }
    
    //More stuff

}

public enum SomeDerivedEnum
{
    //Some Enum Values
}

public enum AnotherDerivedEnum
{
    //Another Enum Values
}

public class SomeDerived : Base
{
    private SomeDerived () : base() {}
    
    public SomeDerived (double doubleProp, SomeDerivedEnum someEnum)
        : base(doubleProp, someEnum)
    {
    }

    //More Stuff

}

public class AnotherDerived : Base
{
    private AnotherDerived () : base() {}
    
    public AnotherDerived (double doubleProp, AnotherDerivedEnum anotherEnum)
        : base(doubleProp, anotherEnum)
    {
    }

    //More Stuff

}
```

When I try to Serialize I get the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException : No serializer defined for type: System.Enum

There's a way to protobuf just convert any System.Enum value to int and back?

Comment: The type `Enum` is the base type for all enum types, but is not an enum type itself. Not all enum types are backed by `int` either -- that's the default, but having `MyEnum : long` would yield an enum type that may not be serializable to an `int`. Because the actual, managed type of an enum value isn't part of the enum value, it would be impossible for protobuf to deserialize an arbitrary value to the "correct" enum type if all it has is `Enum`. In short, if you want `int` serialization, use `int`; convert to enums later as necessary (through separate properties, for example).

Comment: As @Jeroen says: use a specific enum type, not the base type

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments! I've found a way based on some other posts I've read.

Responding to first comments, I cannot define a specific enum on base class because I don't know it beforehand, each derived class has its own enum. So I've came up with a different approach.

First I've added a function:

On Base:

```
protected virtual Type GetEnumtype() => typeof(Enum)
```

On SomeDerived (for example)

```
 protected override Type GetEnumType() => typeof(SomeDeviredEnum);
```

Then I've created a intermediate private int property to serialize my enums and used the override function to make the conversion back.

```
[ProtoMember(2)]
private int intPvtProp 
{ 
    get => System.Convert.ToInt32(EnumProp); 
    set => EnumProp = (Enum)Enum.ToObject(GetEnumType(), value); 
}

public Enum EnumProp { get; }
```

I really don't know if is the best way to do it, but it works!

Comment: There seems to be almost no value in `EnumProp`, though, in that clients cannot meaningfully use it without knowing the type (functionally it's almost no different from declaring `EnumProp` as `object`). Given that that is the case, you might as well keep the `int` and make whatever code is using the `EnumProp` now responsible for the conversion, rather than this property.

Comment: Alternatively, remove `EnumProp` from the base, give it a `protected int`,  and let each class simply use its own enum type in a strongly-typed fashion (`public DerivedEnum EnumProp { get => (DerivedEnum) BaseInt; set => BaseInt = (int) value; }`). This means there is no relationship between `EnumProp`s of different classes, but the notion of "inheritance" between enums is suspect to begin with (there is nothing to enforce a subset relationship). And, again, accessing the enums in a type-agnostic manner would mean casting,`object` or `dynamic`, none of which is more convenient than an `int`.